# Angular 5 npm install requires peer issue

Tags: angular, npm

We have an Angular solution that works perfectly on one machine however on another it throws up errors when the below command is run...

```
npm install
```

The errors that appear are...

```
npm WARN angular4-social-login@1.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.28 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.28 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-moment@0.8.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@~2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@~2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/router@~3.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@~5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-page-scroll@3.2.3 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.23 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-img-cropper@0.9.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-img-cropper@0.9.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-img-cropper@0.9.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng4-geoautocomplete@0.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-social-share@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-social-share@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-social-share@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-social-share@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@5.0.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.24.1 requires a peer of typescript@2.4.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none was installed.
```

The packages.json dependencies section looks like this...

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.1.0",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.2.9",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.2",
    "angular4-social-login": "^1.1.1",
    "angulartics2": "^1.6.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.2.6",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "^3.2.3",
    "ng2-social-share": "^0.0.10",
    "ng4-geoautocomplete": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
```

We can't work out why this is happening on one machine but not another. One machine must have something different installed on it maybe?

The project was built from this starter pack
https://github.com/bencameron00/angular-starter

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the version of npm differ between to 2 machines?

Comment: If you use lower that `^5.x.x,` npm version (means you dont have **package-lock.json**), you can try to remove all `~` and `^` from **package.json** . I never tried this myself, but why not??

Comment: That was it, the tilders were causing an issue. If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment the solution was to remove the tilders...

"If you use lower that ^5.x.x, npm version (means you don't have package-lock.json), you can try to remove all ~ and ^ from package.json".